# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager request POST to server Java

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am developer iOS. I have a problem about AFHTTPRequestOperationManager request POST to server(JBoss) Java. When I request POST with Multipart is good response, and not problem. But, when I request POST only string to server, server show me error:

> 11:57:19,815 ERROR [UserRest] Problem on login email: null password:
>   null 11:57:19,817 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.Exception: MISSING ARGUMENTS

This show me, send parameters null. This method:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

I don't understand, why send parameters null.. My code is:

```
NSString *strURL = @"http://YOUR_IP/YOUR_PATH/login";
__block const NSString *strResultResponse = @"";

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager     = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = NO;

AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializerRequest = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializerRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


AFJSONResponseSerializer *serializerResponse = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
serializerResponse.readingOptions = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments;
serializerResponse.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

manager.requestSerializer = serializerRequest;
manager.responseSerializer = serializerResponse;

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email":@"xxxxxx@xxxx.xxxx",@"password":@"xxxx"};

[manager POST:strURL parameters:parameters
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString);    
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString);
}];
```

I tried many ways, but not result. Please help me.